# Style link based on active route in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a Navlink element as follows:

```
  <NavLink isActive={this.isActiveFunc.bind(this)} className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/admin/users" }}>
       <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
           <ListItemText inset primary="Users" />
       </ListItem>
  </NavLink>
```

When this link is active I want the ListItemText to be styled differently. To do this I tried applying the following logic

```
 isActiveFunc = (match, location) => {
    this.setState({activePath: match.path});
    return match
  };
```

Whereafter I can set the style if the `activePath` state matches the `to` path. However, this yields an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null

Answer (score 0):

How much control do you have over styling the ListItemText?  Can you pass it a prop or className if it is active?:

```
<NavLink className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/admin/users" }}>
   <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
       <ListItemText inset primary="Users" passDownAClassName={props.match.path == "/admin/users" ? 'active-class' : 'inactive-class'} />
   </ListItem>
</NavLink>
```

Or :

```
<NavLink className={classes.subLink} to={{ pathname: "/admin/users" }}>
   <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
       <ListItemText inset primary="Users" isActive={props.match.path == "/admin/users"} />
   </ListItem>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to be that props.match.path is undefined